# JSON get parsed in browser but not by node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mocha.js

i'm about to write some test for my client UI.

the weird thing, my JSON string:

```
{"match":"\s?5\.7\s?\<=\>\s?7","success":"null-coalesce-operator"}
```

used to be parsed by JSON.parse by browser(Chrome) and looks like this:

```
{ 
  match: "\s?5\.7\s?\<=\>\s?7",
  success:"null-coalesce-operator"
}
```

everything is fine,

but when i run that part by mocha within node.js env, i get:

```
{"match":"\s?5\.7\s?\<=\>\s?7","success":"null-coalesce-operator"}
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
    at Object.parse (native)
    ...
```

did anyone experienced stuff like this. thx for any tipp.

node version is **v5.7.1**

mocha version is  **2.4.5**

**UPDATE** html string that i test is:

```
<!doctype html><html><body><div data-meta="{&quot;match&quot;:&quot;\\s?5\\.7\\s?\\<=\\>\\s?7&quot;,&quot;success&quot;:&quot;null-coalesce-operator&quot;}"></div></body></html>
```

it just a single line string without any **\n** newlines and the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because it also parse specials characaters (e.g \n => line feed, \r => carriage return, etc), what chrome did not. So because you want an antislash in you regex, before parsing in node, you need to replace each`\` by `\\`:

```
json_string = json_string.replace(new RegExp('\\\\', 'g'), '\\\\') //we have to use regex, because when using replace with string, it only replaces the first occurence...
```

otherwise, when parsing, it will tell,  à \s : 'It is a special character, identified by s. But I haven't any tokens s. So I throw an error."

Comment: sorry, but it changes the RegEx as well, the expression have to be the same for convenience reason. I just ask me, why in that case it's not a problem for browser's JSON.parse

Comment: It DOESN'T change the regexpr! did you tested? because you write **two** antislashs within the string, the string contains **one** ! So the regex reads `\s` ... But I don't know why it works on the browser, I've tested it on chromium, it throws the same error

Comment: jo, i tested it: i get  { match: '\\s?5\\.7\\s?\\<=\\>\\s?7', ...}

Comment: After parsing? It shouldn't be... the error you have is throwed because of what I told, it is written `Unexpected token s`!

Comment: ok, i isolated the whole thing in a sandbox, and now i have this ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s``` also in a Browser.  very interesting... anyway thank you Vincent for your input.

Comment: Please mark it as the right answer if it solved your problem.